# A question about a formula of Pfaffian

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$is a closed oriented 2n-dimensional smooth manifold, $E$ is a 2n-dimensional oriented real vector bundle on $M$, with inner product on each fibers.
Let $\tau=(\sqrt{-1})^{n}c(e_{1})c(e_{2})...c(e_{2n})$, use it we can define a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading on $\wedge(E^{*})\otimes\mathbb{C}=\wedge_{+}(E^{*})\otimes\mathbb{C}\oplus\wedge_{-}(E^{*})\otimes\mathbb{C}$, the Clifford action is defined by $c(v)\alpha=\varepsilon(v)\alpha-\iota(v)\alpha$.

I read a formula about Pfaffian like this:

$$Str[exp(-R^{\wedge(E^{*})\otimes\mathbb{C}})]=2^{n}(\sqrt{-1})^{-n}{\rm Pf}(-R^{E})$$

here $R^{E}$ and $R^{\wedge(E^{*})\otimes\mathbb{C}}$ are curvatures,

$E^{*}$ is the dual to $E$.

How to proof this formula? or any matrial about this? If anyone can tell me something I will be very thanks.

Comment: Am I right in interpreting $\tau$ as the "volume element" in the Clifford bundle $Cl(E)$?

Comment: Yes,it is complex volume element. 

Comment: Two comments: (1) this ought to be a linear-algebraic identity, so it should be true for skewsymmetric endomorphisms, not necessarily curvatures; and (2) did you try looking at the paper of Matthai and Quillen *Superconnections, Thom classes and differential forms*?  They have similar formula in terms of "fermion Gaussian integrals".

Comment: Thanks! Professor. I try to looking at that paper, but I didn't understand how the curvature $R^{\wedge(E^{*})\otimes\mathbb{C}}$
changed to be the curvature $R^{E}$, what is the relation?

Comment: There is an embedding of $\mathfrak{so}(E)$ into the Clifford algebra $Cl(E)$ and hence an action of $\mathfrak{so}(E)$ on $Cl(E)$ via the Clifford commutator.  The exterior algebra is the associated graded algebra to $Cl(E)$ relative to the filtration coming from writing $Cl(E)$ as a quotient of the tensor algebra.  The action on $Cl(E)$ induces an action on the exterior algebra.  Now read David Bar Moshe's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supertrace can be evaluated either by Berezin Gaussian integration, or equivalently by 
summation over a Clifford algebra. Here is a description of the second method.

Let $\omega$ be a skew-symmetric 2n by 2n matrix. Let $\{{\ e_1, e_2, . . . . e_{2n} \}}$ be a real
2n-dimensional Clifford algebra. Then:

$exp(\Sigma_{k,l=1}^{2n} \omega_{kl} e_k e_l) = \Sigma_{|K|  even} Pf(\omega_K)  \hat{e}_K$

where: $K$ is a subset of $\{{ 1, 2, . . . . 2n \}}$ and $\hat{e}_K$ is the corresponding wedge product of the Clifford generators and $\omega_K$ is the skew-symmeterized submatrix containg only the rows and columns in $K$.

Now, the supertrace selects the coefficient of the top form, giving you the required formula.

A proof of this result can be found for example in the following [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJIwWbh1isC&pg=PA204&lpg=PA204&dq=Pfaffian+%252B+%2522Berezin+integral%2522&source=bl&ots=ex-Shnj--R&sig=jRCLVTeXucsrtVVYi-rZDc1PCMI&hl=en&ei=ssBzTMqXMM_uOZuy2OUI&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Pfaffian%2520%252B%2520%2522Berezin%2520integral%2522&f=false) by: José Gracia Bondía, Joseph C. Várilly, Héctor Figueroa.